# change length of each burst in multipart file upload in android

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, multipartentity

Is there some way to limit the parts size that are sent on a MultipartEntity from the org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity . I am using volley for network requests. I have tried extending the Volley request class and overriding the getbody() method.

Comment: Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225396/can-http-multipart-and-chunking-coexist to see if it can help or not

Comment: And the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199080/httpclient-problem-to-do-a-post-of-a-multipart-in-chunked-mode

Comment: Outside specifics of your implementation ( volley ) have you consider just 'chunked' encoded declaration in Http headers?   or , more involve, in building/config the socket used by Http Conn , have you consider tweek on the buffer sizes ( SndBuf, RcvBuf ) ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html?is-external=true#SO_RCVBUF   https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConfiguration.java  Not clear why your app code needs to get involve at that layer of framework?